# Oracle date time format

Tags: database, oracle

In the oracle table, the datetime value is stored like this:

> 44412,46854418982

What is this format? How can I convert it to DateTime format?

Comment: We currently have no clues what date/time that's meant to represent. Do you have *any* information about it?

Comment: is that stored as a varchar2 data type?

Comment: Oracle has DATE and TIMESTAMP types, DateTime is class in the .NET framework. This is probably ticks.

Answer (score 1):

> What is this format?

It looks like a number formatted using a comma as the decimal separator.

We have no way of knowing what it means beyond that; you should ask the developer who created the table what it is meant to represent or consult the design documentation for the database (assuming that they created some documentation).

---

We can possibly guess that it could be days since `1900-01-01` and if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 44412.46854418982 FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can convert it using:

```sql
SELECT value,
       DATE '1900-01-01' + value As date_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, with the NLS settings:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=',.';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | DATE_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 44412,46854418982 | 2021-08-06 11:14:42 |

However, you could just as easily pick any other epoch and any other time interval and use that:

```sql
SELECT value,
       DATE '1970-01-01' + value * INTERVAL '1' HOUR As hours_since_1970,
       DATE '1970-01-01' + value As days_since_1970,
       DATE '2000-01-01' + value * INTERVAL '1' SECOND As seconds_since_2000
FROM   table_name;
```

Which outputs:

> | VALUE | HOURS_SINCE_1970 | DAYS_SINCE_1970 | SECONDS_SINCE_2000 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 44412,46854418982 | 1975-01-25 12:28:06 | 2091-08-06 11:14:42 | 2000-01-01 12:20:12 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=439a785bbd01b80ba4ba8233139487aa)*